# How to dynamically change link name in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to change the link name of my Excel documents dynamically for all relevant files in the folder (in this case the ones with v1.0 at the end). For that I'm opening the relevant files as well as the new file to which they should change the link to (both files have similar names which is why I use the MID() function to get the correct files). Unfortuneatly I get the error: runtimer error 1004: The method "ChangeLink" for the object "_Workbook" failed.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
Dim x, y As Workbook
Dim myPath, fname As String

myPath = "C:\Path\File\"

Set fso = Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("G:\Path\File\")

fname = Dir(myPath & "*v1.0.xlsx")

Do while fname <> ""

    Set x = Workbooks.Open(myPath & fname)
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "\Daten" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 31, Len(fname) - 25) & "v1.1test.xlsx")

    x.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
        fldr & "\Daten" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 12, Len(fname) - 25) & "v1.0.xlsx" _
        , NewName:= myPath & "Daten" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 12, Len(fname) - 25) & "v1.1.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

    fname = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Would be happy about any help!
Best regards

Comment: Probably not the solution but I'm curious: `Set fso = Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` is actually working?

Comment: Upps, I dont't know. Must have been a mistake when typing it in here...anyways I found the solution. There were just some mistakes when in the ChangeLink line